# Find rows in a dataframe which contain all elements of a row of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains three columns, and a second which contains two columns.

```
df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'), 
                  X2 = c('B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'C'), 
                  X3 = c('C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'D'))

df2 <- data.frame(X1 = c('A', 'A'), 
                  X2 = c('B', 'D'))
```

Questions:

1. How do I find the rows in `df1` which contain all the elements of a row of `df2`? i.e. rows 1:3 of `df1` contain both `A` and `B` (first row of `df2`). I am looking to remove any rows of `df1` which contain both elements of the rows of `df2`. So in the example, I would like to remove rows 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6 of `df1` as these include `A` and `B` OR `A` and `D`.
2. Is there a quick way to count the number of rows for each row of `df2` without looping? i.e. `df2` row 1 would have a count of 3 and row 2 a count of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *apply*:

```
df1[ !apply(df1, 1, function(i) any(apply(df2, 1, function(j) all(j %in% i)))), ]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 5  A  C  E
# 7  B  C  D
```

Do the similar loops for *df2* match counts:

```
cbind(df2, 
      cnt = apply(df2, 1, function(i) sum(apply(df1, 1, function(j) all(i %in% j)))))
#   X1 X2 cnt
# 1  A  B   3
# 2  A  D   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is base R option using `outer` + `intersect`

```
mat <- lengths(
  outer(
    asplit(df1, 1),
    asplit(df2, 1),
    Vectorize(intersect)
  )
) >= ncol(df2)
```

and you will obtain

```
> subset(df1, !rowSums(mat))
  X1 X2 X3
5  A  C  E
7  B  C  D

> within(df2, cnt <- colSums(mat))
  X1 X2 cnt
1  A  B   3
2  A  D   3
```

- `asplit` splits the data frames by rows
- `outer` produces all combinations of rows from `df1` and `df2`
- `intersect` gives the intersected elements of rows from two data frames
- `subset` selects the rows which has less than one common elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop somehow. Here is one way to do it using `dplyr` and `purrr`:

**1.**

```
for(iRow in seq_len(nrow(df2))){
  
  df1 <- df1 %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    filter(!all(as.character(df2[iRow,]) %in% c_across(everything())))
}
```

**2.**

```
df2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(n = sum(map_int(transpose(df1), ~all(c_across(everything()) %in% .x))))
```

Just be sure to do 2nd part before 1st because 1st part removes rows. Also you can first detect which rows to remove for each row of `df2`. This way you can count them and afterwards remove them.

```
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    indices = list(which(map_lgl(transpose(df1), ~all(c_across(everything()) %in% .x))))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(n = map_int(indices, length))

df1 <- df2[["indices"]] %>%
  unlist() %>%
  unique() %>%
  "*"(-1) %>%
  df1[.,]

df2 <- df2 %>% select(-indices)
```